# Is there any possibility to duplicate a shop page in woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, layout, woocommerce

I need to develop two layouts of shop page. Both are with different structures. One has shorting option but does not have side bar filtering option and the other one has side bar filter option but does not have sorting option.

Both layouts have different count of product listing.

1. 1st layout has 4 product having sorting options like "List and grid view
   button" and "Short By" option etc..., but this layout don't have
   filter option in side bar.

> 1st layout i get from as usual  woocommerce shop page method. And i complete it.

2. And the other one has 8 products and this layout have right side bar
   filter option, but this layout don't have sorting option.

> For another shop page, I tried with custom template using woocommerce product shortcode.

Shortcode:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true"]
```

But it does not have pagination option.

Note: From the custom template layout i cant able to display the pagination option. I need pagination option on custom template shop page. And i need sidebar filtering option on this custom template shop page.

Comment: Can you try to clarify, post some example code of what you have done?

Comment: try to set limit in shortcode

Comment: Now i explained better, please lookup. Thank you.